# How can I open windows explorer and save a file path to a text box in Matlab?

Tags: windows, matlab, filepath, explorer

I need MATLAB to be able to open up Windows explorer so that the user can select a file and upon pressing 'Open' in explorer, Matlab will take the filepath of the selected file and display it in a text box.

I've been using the winopen command and can get explorer open, but cannot seem to find a way to proceed with the rest of my functionality.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe uigetfile is what you need:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html

Comment: Thanks man, got it to work. Used the 
[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile(FilterSpec,DialogTitle)